# Using Session in GridView, ASP.net IN C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, session, gridview

I would like to get the `Candidate_id` (Primary key) of the selected row.  and pass the value to the other Web form using session.
ASP CODE

---

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" DataKeyNames="Candidate_id" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1" OnSelectedIndexChanged="GridView1_SelectedIndexChanged">
        <Columns>
            <asp:BoundField DataField="Candidate_id" HeaderText="Candidate_id" ReadOnly="True" SortExpression="Candidate_id" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="Candidate_Name" HeaderText="Candidate_Name" SortExpression="Candidate_Name" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="ContactNumber" HeaderText="ContactNumber" SortExpression="ContactNumber" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="Email" HeaderText="Email" SortExpression="Email" />
            <asp:HyperLinkField DataNavigateUrlFields="Candidate_id" DataNavigateUrlFormatString="EditCandidate.aspx?Candidate_id=[0]" DataTextField="Candidate_id" HeaderText="Edit" />

        </Columns>
    </asp:GridView>
```

C# CODE

---

```
protected void GridView1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Session["id"] = GridView1.SelectedRow.Cells[0].Text.ToString();

            Response.Redirect("~/EditCandidate.aspx");
        }
```

how do i access the Session["id"] in the other page?
I have tried to access the `Session["id"]` but still getting null. please help!

---

C# Code in the other page

```
 protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
              TextBox3.Text = (String)Session["id"];
        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please verify the session mode in your application web.config and specify the options

```
<sessionState mode="Off|InProc|StateServer|SQLServer"
          cookieless="true|false"
          timeout="number of minutes"
          stateConnectionString="tcpip=server:port"
          sqlConnectionString="sql connection string"
          stateNetworkTimeout="number of seconds"/>
```

timeout - Specifies the number of minutes a session can be idle before it is abandoned. The default is 20.

Source : [SessionSate](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/h6bb9cz9(v=vs.71).aspx)

Also in your last snippet use the check ispostback , its the good programming practice ensures that page has load the first time (no post back)

```
 protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
             if(!isPostBack){
              TextBox3.Text = (String)Session["id"].ToString(); }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you should verify how is your web.Config configured and verify how is your page configured. Check this docs:

[System.web Pages EnableSessionState](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/950xf363%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

[System.web SessionState](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/h6bb9cz9%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

[EnableSessionState](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/system.web.configuration.pagessection.enablesessionstate%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)